# Tomcat multiple Apps, ehcache wont work

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, ehcache, c3p0

I have startet multiple Identical Apps in Tomcat (They display different content but the code is the same). These Apps use Hibernate and ehcache.

The Problem is: A singel Application works as expected. but adding a second one will make everything crash with nullpointerexception.

The configuration is:

```
        // Caching
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
        cfg.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "com/gfop/util/hibernate/ehcache.xml");
        // Query Caching
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        cfg.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads", "1");
```

This is the Stacktrace:

```
    2016-06-28 17:57:31,766 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] ERROR myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateDBServerInstance.getSessionFactory(?:?) - Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateDBServerInstance.getSessionFactory(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateDBServerInstance.getSystemSession(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateDBServerInstance.getSystemSession(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateService.getSystemSession(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.service.BwvMandantService.getList(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.bean.ApplicationBean.getMandantenList(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.bean.AusschreibungBean.init(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.bean.AusschreibungBean.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:54)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:303)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:266)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:96)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:1153)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlDataTableHack.createDataModel(HtmlDataTableHack.java:957)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.AbstractHtmlDataTable.createDataModel(AbstractHtmlDataTable.java:1605)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlDataTableHack.getDataModel(HtmlDataTableHack.java:932)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.AbstractHtmlDataTable.getDataModel(AbstractHtmlDataTable.java:1597)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlDataTableHack.getRowCount(HtmlDataTableHack.java:103)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlTableRendererBase.encodeInnerHtml(HtmlTableRendererBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlTableRendererBase.encodeChildren(HtmlTableRendererBase.java:214)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.ext.HtmlTableRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTableRenderer.java:366)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:488)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:609)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:370)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:618)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.actuallyRenderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:322)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:181)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-06-28 17:57:31,767 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] ERROR myGroup.bwv.bean.ApplicationBean.getMandantenList(?:?) - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateDBServerInstance.getSystemSession(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateDBServerInstance.getSystemSession(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.sv.hibernate.HibernateService.getSystemSession(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.service.BwvMandantService.getList(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.bean.ApplicationBean.getMandantenList(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.bean.AusschreibungBean.init(Unknown Source)
    at myGroup.bwv.bean.AusschreibungBean.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:54)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:303)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:266)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:96)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:1153)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlDataTableHack.createDataModel(HtmlDataTableHack.java:957)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.AbstractHtmlDataTable.createDataModel(AbstractHtmlDataTable.java:1605)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlDataTableHack.getDataModel(HtmlDataTableHack.java:932)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.AbstractHtmlDataTable.getDataModel(AbstractHtmlDataTable.java:1597)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlDataTableHack.getRowCount(HtmlDataTableHack.java:103)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlTableRendererBase.encodeInnerHtml(HtmlTableRendererBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlTableRendererBase.encodeChildren(HtmlTableRendererBase.java:214)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.ext.HtmlTableRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTableRenderer.java:366)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:488)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:609)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:370)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:618)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.actuallyRenderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:322)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:181)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Have you ever experienced anything like this? Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - i.e. the stack trace (and relevant code) would be useful

Comment: @jozefChocholacek added Stacktrace. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You use `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`, you should use `EhCacheRegionFactory`. Now you have only singleton, so you are not able to get different instance, it is singlet :) Change it to EhCacheRegionFactory and it souhl be able to get another instance

Comment: @Harabosch i already tried that, it altered the Stacktrace but it did not eliminate it.